# JTable clone / not the model

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable and delete some columns of it. Once I deleted the columns, I need to copy this JTable.

I can not copy the model, because the model still include the deleted columns. So how can I copy the "**Visible Model**"?

I do not really need to copy the graphical Swing-Component of a JTable, I just need the "Visible Model" of it.

Comment: What do you mean by copy? Do you mean to say that there is another frame in which you have to display the copied table without the columns?

Comment: That´s exactly what I mean!   ...                              -

Comment: Simply create a copy of the TableModel object as a new object without the columns that you don't want and use this new tableModel as the model for the new JTable

Comment: I have a JTable with deleted columns, later on I don´t know the deleted columns. Only the JTable self knows it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, it´s so simple. You need to place also the ColumnModel in the new JTable:

```
JTable jtb = new JTable(ptable.getModel(), ptable.getColumnModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TableColumn col = jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
jtable.getColumnModel().removeColumn(col);

jtable.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
jtable.getmodel();
```

the thing is you have to call  `jtable.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);`
  other wise you'll get a new column again after deleting the column. try this
  way. then you can pass the model the it wont contain the removed column.note that its a property in the jtable so calling the method `setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false)` one time is enough.

Comment: Don´t work, if I call it before or after column deletion. :(

Comment: so your new model still contain the deleted column?

Comment: Yes, the new model contains the deleted columns.